# Get the list of children element inside parent element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, web-scraping, nokogiri

```
<div class="separate">
<h1 class="rc-header">...</h1>
<div class="rc-wrapper">...</div>
Somethig goes here
<p>....</p>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the value inside the p tag. I tried doing `street_soup.search(".//div[@class='seperate']")[0].search(".//p")` and it gives me the p's inside of the h1 and the child div as well. I just want to get the value of p of the parent not its child's p's. Any idea how I can do it?

Comment: When asking a question it's important your input data demonstrates the problem. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". You want the `<p>` tags inside `<h1>`, then say you want the value of the `<p>` of the parent not its children but neither case occurs in the input. Providing accurate information is really important because, without it, it slows us when we try to help you as we try to figure out what you mean. It also opens up the possibility we won't recreate the missing data correctly, resulting in wrong answers, neither of which helps you or others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
"./p"
```

How does this work?

- `//` will match any descendant
- `/` matches children only